# Provide liquidity to Uniswap without initial funds on one side?

Tags: tokens, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

Is there a way to provide liquidity to Uniswap-like contracts without initial funds on one side of the trade?

For example, if I create my own token called Token, I believe this token should be worth one dollar each.

I have one thousand tokens, but I don't have one thousand dollars.

I would like to sell these tokens on Uniswap (or similar DeX) for at least one dollar. Is that possible?

Obviously, there would only be liquidity in one direction initially (from Token to dollar), but once people buy enough Token, it will gradually balance out the pool and thus there will be liquidity in the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to provide liquidity to Uniswap-like contracts without initial funds on one side of the trade?

No. Because by definition, this would not be liquidity.

> For example, if I create my own token called Token, I believe this token should be worth one dollar each.

> have one thousand tokens, but I don't have one thousand dollars.

You cannot do such a trade on open markets. Instead, you can do [a crowdsale](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales) where you can lock the price as the only counterparty who can sell.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I was going to do a crowdsale, but figured it would be a better user experience if I could do it through a DeX like Uniswap instead.

Comment: You cant have it paired against zero, but you can create the liquidity against some meaningless amount. You could have 1 billion tokens paired against .0001 ETH. So the tokens are essentially worthless, but do some mathematical value that isnt zero.